# How to remove extra spaces that don't register as white space in R

Tags: r, removing-whitespace

I'm scraping college basketball data and some of the schools have a portion that on the website is in superscript (NCAA part) and I want to remove that space before NCAA and then eventually the NCAA part but the space before doesn't register as white space because it is superscript online and gsub and str_replace don't work when just putting a space as it normally would

```
> head(cbb$School)
[1] "Air Force"               "Akron NCAA"              "Alabama A&M"             "Alabama-Birmingham NCAA" "Alabama State NCAA"      "Alabama"
> cbb$StrReplace <- str_replace_all(cbb$School, " ","")
> head(cbb$StrReplace)
[1] "AirForce"                "Akron NCAA"              "AlabamaA&M"              "Alabama-Birmingham NCAA" "AlabamaState NCAA"       "Alabama" 
> cbb$Gsub <- gsub(" ", "", cbb$School, fixed = TRUE)
> head(cbb$StrReplace)
[1] "AirForce"                "Akron NCAA"              "AlabamaA&M"              "Alabama-Birmingham NCAA" "AlabamaState NCAA"       "Alabama"
```

So I want it to have an output like

```
[1] "AirForce"      "AkronNCAA"       "AlabamaA&M"      "Alabama-BirminghamNCAA"  
    "AlabamaStateNCAA"       "Alabama"
```

Comment: Try `"\\s"` instead of `" "`.

Comment: Can you possibly share where you're getting the data from? Otherwise, try `"\\s"` as @MartinGal suggested above.